# selecting option in dynamcially generated select boxes when id is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a html select boxes dynamically. The select boxes have a name:value pair of the number of total select boxes. That said, if I have 4 select boxes, then in each of the select box should have options like:

```
<select id="dynamic_id" >
       <option value=1>1</option>
       <option value=2>2</option>
       <option value=3>3</option>
       <option value=4>4</option>
   </select>
```

. That I've accomplished already. Now I want option 1 to be selected for the first select box, option 2 to be selected for the second select box and so on.
(I am a complete noob and maintainig someone's code. So the code is pretty ugly but if you guys should need it...I will post it.)

**EDIT**
At the moment, abdulla's suggestion is working a bit but not fully. It always selects the first item only. Guys, this is a horrible code, but I think only it can help you understand mistakes I'm making:

```
 var r_count=0;
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var newId; var tableName; var display_table;

 $(".clickable").each(function(i,l){

 $(l).click(function(){
     var parentId = $(this).parents("div")[0].id;
     var li = $(this).parents("li")[0];
     var liIndex = $(li).parent().find("li").index(li);
     newId = parentId + "_" + liIndex;

     if(this.checked) {
         display_table = $("#display_board");
         var newtr = $(".data_table_template").clone();
         tableName = $($(this).parents("table")[0]).find("th").text().trim();
         var columnName = $(this).parent().text().trim();

         newtr.attr("id",newId);
         newtr.attr("class","");
         newtr.show();
         newtr.find("td").each(function(i,l){

         if(i==0)
             $(this).html(columnName)
         else if(i==2)
             $(this).html(tableName)
         else if(i==3){
             $(this).each(function(i,l){
                 $(this).find("#checkbox").attr("id", "chkbx_" + newId);
             });
         }
         else if(i==4){
             $(this).each(function(i,l){
                  //$(this).find("#select").html();
                  /* Generate new id for the table item dynamically*/
                  $(this).find("#select").attr("id", "sort_type_" + newId);
                  $(this).find(".sel1").attr("name", "sort_type_" + newId);
                  $(this).find("#checkbox").attr("id", "sort_type_" + newId);
             });
         }
         else if(i==5)
             $(this).each(function(m,l){
                 /* Generate new id for the table item dynamically*/
                 $(this).find("#select2").attr("id", "sort_order_" + newId);
                 $(this).find(".sel2").attr("name", "sort_order_" + newId);
             });
        });

        display_table.append(newtr);
        r_count++;

        // addOption is from another jquery plugin            
        $(".sel2").addOption(r_count+1, r_count+1);

        // as suggested in the answer
        $('select').each(function (index, item) {
        $(this).children('option:nth-child(' + (index +1) + ')').attr('selected',      'selected');
});

} else {
                            r_count--;
                            //$("#" + newId).find("#chkbx_"+newId).attr('checked','');
                            $("#" + newId).remove();
                            $(".sel2").addOption(r_count, r_count);
                        }


                    }

                );
                });
```

Only the select boxes in the 5th column are in consideration.

Comment: What about @Jakub's code? How can you say something is working if it actually is not? abdulla's solution assumes that the select boxes are siblings.

Comment: with Jakub's code, the items are being displayed properly but the desired items are not being selected. It may be because, I've an extra ``Unsorted`` option in the select list.

Comment: Is it the first option? Then just add one to `index`.

Comment: @Felix Kling The first option is actually "unsorted" which is hard coded into the html. The remaining 1,2,3,4 are added dynamically thru jquery. At the moment I don't want "unsorted" (which is the first option) to be selected in any of the select boxes; instead 1 in the first select box and so on... (Sorry for all the fuss..its only my second day and I dont know why they gave me this to fix this.

Comment: As I said, instead of `this.selectedIndex = index;` you can write `this.selectedIndex = index + 1;` then.

Comment: Ya I did that...but the options are being selected in few select boxes only.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select').each(function(index, value) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
});
```

Comment: +1 That'st the best answer as it does not make any assumptions about the values and does not unnecessarily use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the select boxes with the option that you wanted having the attribute:

```
selected="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works, by setting the selected="selected" property on the children..

```
$('select').each(function (index, item) {
    $(this).children('option:nth-child(' + (index +1) + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood correctly, i assume you have the following markup

```
<select id="dynamic_id" >
       <option value=1>1</option>
       <option value=2>2</option>
       <option value=3>3</option>
       <option value=4>4</option>
</select><br/>
<select id="dynamic_id2" >
       <option value=1>1</option>
       <option value=2>2</option>
       <option value=3>3</option>
       <option value=4>4</option>
</select><br/>
<select id="dynamic_id3" >
       <option value=1>1</option>
       <option value=2>2</option>
       <option value=3>3</option>
       <option value=4>4</option>
</select><br/>
<select id="dynamic_id4" >
       <option value=1>1</option>
       <option value=2>2</option>
       <option value=3>3</option>
       <option value=4>4</option>
   </select>
```

you can try

```
$("select").each(function(index){
    index=index+1;

$(this).find("option[value='"+index+"']").attr("selected","selected");

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/skyWJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).val(index + 1).change();
});
```

Comment: Does not seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/NHyXw/ And this will only work if the values are actually numeric and continuous.

Comment: @Felix Kling But it works for me. Would you please clarify me

Comment: In the fiddle I linked to, the selected values are `1, 2, 4, 1`. I'm using Chrome 13.

Comment: @Flex Kling I'm also using Chrome 13, hah!

Comment: Ah I see now. First you probably want to add one to the index, as the option's values start with 1. Second, it breaks if there are other elements between the the select boxes. It totally fails if the select boxes don't have a common parent, see: http://jsfiddle.net/NHyXw/2/